# Need help with a work around

Tags: calculated-column, flow, powerapp

I need to take the 'Office' display of the 'Created By' column and display the first 5 digits of it so that my flows can run a conditional check on it. The reason is that Microsoft flows has all the 'Created By' dynamic contents besides 'Office'.

I figured simple enough I'll just do a calculated column on the SharePoint list. Then I find out that 'Created By' cannot be used in calculated columns.

So I figured I'll have my PowerApp write the Users 'Office' as a default to a field when submitting a form and calculate it off that column. Unfortunately PowerApps only has User().FullName, Email, and Image.

I have pretty much exhausted the options for a workaround that my knowledge will allow. Hopefully someone might have some ideas.

Comment: Still attempting to find a solution. Haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems that this is not a property of the user that you can grab I'd suggest just adding a column for Office and giving your users a dropdown list to pick from.